# Strange JQuery $.Ajax() behavior using JSONP datatype: How to fix?

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonp

This is a working JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "GetJSON",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (j) {
        myFunctionName(j);
    }
});
```

And another nearly identical JSONP request that also works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "GetJSONP",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (j) {
        myFunctionName(j);
    }
});
```

Now if you swap out success: for a jsonpCallback: on the second request, it calls the function myFunctionName twice.  The result from the server is myFunctionName( [jsondata] ) where [jsondata] is the json encoded data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "GetJSONP",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "myFunctionName"
});
```

What am I doing wrong in the third code example that calls myFunctionName twice?

**Answer:**

In ASP.NET MVC 3, I used this:

```
public class JsonpResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult( ControllerContext c)
}
```

And this:

```
public static JsonpResult Jsonp(this Controller c, object d)
{    
    JsonpResult r = new JsonpResult();
    r.Data = d;
    // r.ExecuteResult(c.ControllerContext);  <== mistake
    return r;
}
```

And this:

```
public JsonpResult GetJSONP()
{
    var service = new Service();
    var data = service.Getdata();
    return this.Jsonp(data);
}
```

The mistake is noted in the comments.  Apparently ASP.NET MVC calls ExecuteResult for you, so calling it manually added the data twice to the result.

Comment: Are you sure your JSONP response isn't including `myFunctionName` in the output twice?

Comment: What is triggering the AJAX request? That third example appears to work as a simple test

Comment: @Spencer: that was it.  Post that as the answer.  Apparently in ASP.NET MVC 3, ActionResult calls ExecuteResult for you.

Comment: Zim: Ah, mentioning ASP.NET MVC would've been important, but glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer from the comments:

> Are you sure your JSONP response isn't
>   including `myFunctionName` in the output
>   twice?